# Can ginger root that's gone bad hurt you if you eat it?

Tags: spoilage, ginger

We use ginger root with a mixture of lemon and other ingredients.

Can ginger root that's gone bad hurt you if you eat it?

Comment: What are the spoilage symptoms - is it dry, rotten, moldy, discoloured, tasting and/or smelling off?

Answer (score 4):

Sure. Most foods can cause you damage if you eat it when spoiled. E.g. if its grown moldy, you don't know if the mold is a safe to eat one or not.